# "summing" functions in F#

Tags: f#, inline

I have a list of functions in F# which are all of type (float -> float -> float -> float).  I want to do some kind of fold on the sequence to get a single function which returns the sum of all of the functions.

For instance, I could pass the values 1.0, 2.0, and 3.0 to every function in the list, and get a return value from each one.  Then I could compute the sum of all of these values.  However, I want to generalize this.

I know how to do this recursively, but I feel like it should be doable in one line.  Is there a concise way to accomplish this task?

Comment: map/fold -> fold/sum? It would be beneficial to add some code, including any [HoF] usage that has been attempted, and the current "non generalized" method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution by @Lee is a one liner you're looking for. If you wanted to save a few characters, you can use `List.sumBy` which first applies a given function to an element of the list (similar to `List.map`) and then sums the result (just like `List.sum`):

```
let sumAll (fs:(_ -> _ -> _ -> float) list) a b c = 
  List.sumBy (fun f -> f a b c) fs
```

Both this and Lee's version uses type annotations to specify that the functions in the list return `float`. This is needed, because otherwise the compiler does not know what kind of numbers you want to sum using `List.sum` (floats, integers, etc.). This ambiguity needs to be resolved to compile the function.

Alternatively, you could mark the function as `inline` and then it would be inlined when you call it (and it would work for multiple different numeric types). You can also pass the `fs` parameter as the last one and use partial function application:

```
let inline sumAll a b c = List.sumBy (fun f -> f a b c)
```

Now you can call it using pipelining as follows:  `fs |> sumAll 1 2 3`.

Comment: It can be simplified to a point-free version: `let inline sumAll() = (|||>) >> List.sumBy`

Answer (score 4):

```
let sumAll (fs: (float -> float -> float -> float) list) a b c = List.map (fun f -> f a b c) fs |> Seq.sum
```

Answer (score 4):

The answers by @Lee and @Tomas are great, but there is a shorter way.

If you can afford passing `(a, b, c)` as a triple upon invocation:

```
let inline sumAll() = (|||>) >> List.sumBy
// usage
let predicates =
    [
        fun a b c -> a
        fun a b c -> b * 42.0 - c
    ]
let ret1 = predicates |> sumAll()(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

It will be also generic:

```
let predicates2 =
    [
        fun a b c -> c - 10
        fun a b c -> a + c * 42
    ]
let ret2 = predicates2 |> sumAll()(1, 2, 3)
```

A more readable way which supports curried arguments:

```
let sumAllCurried a b c = (a,b,c) |> (|||>) |> List.sumBy<_, float> 
// usage
let ret3 = predicates |> sumAllCurried 1.0 2.0 3.0
```

Note, I'm using a type parameter on `List.sumBy` since it looks shorter than typing an entire type specification for `f`.